# Python split lines from a web log

Tags: python, list, loops, split

I need to split lines in to variables.

Here is an example of 2 lines:

```
port11.annex1.naples.net [30:00:00:03] "GET /logos/small_gopher.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 935
port11.annex1.naples.net [30:00:00:03] "GET /icons/book.gif" 200 935
```

However, as you can see sometimes a line is missing one piece.

How can I split this without errors?

Currently I am using:

```
for x in log.readlines():
        data = x.split(" ")
        hostname = data[0]
        time = data[1]
        command = data[2]
        resource = data[3]
        version = data[4]
        status = data[5]
        size = data[6]
```

This gives errors, because not every line has 7 "items"

Maybe I should use multiple delimiters to split, however I can't find a good way that works...

Comment: So if not all 5 pieces are present, what do you want the code to do? Return the last piece? If so, then `data[-1]` will do the trick.

Comment: data[-1] would return `935` for the first line, while `200` is the host name returned by data[5]. So I don't think he always wants the last item.

Comment: Maarten - you've posted 2 lines for which data[5] returns what you want. I think for anyone to answer this question, you need to also post a line where data[5] does not get you the hostname you want (e.g. returns an error), and then explain what the rule is that determines where the hostname is in your string/list (since it's apparetly not always the 5th item in a space-delimited list)

Comment: I want every piece. I need to create a parser for this log file. So I want ti split the lines so I can create functions for sorting etc...

Comment: you still need to post a line of data that throws the error, and then explain how it should be handled. right now I don't think it's possible to answer your question because no one has your data and no one knows how you want lines handled that have fewer than 7 items.

Comment: The error I get: IndexError: list index out of range when I print for example "status"

Comment: I would recommend to use regular expressions, since using the position can make deal with too many special cases.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not doing it like this? Suppose your log string is this one:

```
log = r'port11.annex1.naples.net [30:00:00:03] "GET /icons/book.gif" 200 935'
data = log.split(" ")
for i in data:
    print i
```

This way you won't have to give the index and will be able to remove hard-coding.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to match the different components of the log. Then you'll ned to check whether the request part consists of command, resource and version or only command and resource. Something like this could work:

```
import re

# open your log file here... 

logmatcher = re.compile("([^ ]+) (\[[:0-9]+\]) (\"[^\"]+\") ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)")

for x in log.readlines():
  res = logmatcher.findall(x)
  if len(res) > 0:
    hostname = res[0][0]
    time = res[0][1]
    req = res[0][2][1:-1].split(" ") #[1:-1] to get rid of the ""
    if len(req) > 2:  # check if request contains the http version
      command = req[0]
      resource = req[1]
      version = req[2]
    else:
      command = req[0]
      resource = req[1]
      version = ""  # there's no version in the request. just use ""
    status = res[0][3]
    size = res[0][4]
```